# Codedeploy setup

Tags: laravel, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy Laravel on AWS using code deploy, I have attached a sample yml file as well.

As the hook:BeforeInstall: will configure the php, mysql and other configuration that will be needed to run the Laravel Application. I need to know whenever the deployment is made will that hook trigger each time? as I don't want to install the php mysql each time, what I want to do is it should run only on first time and for all other deployments it should not install configurations again.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /*
    destination: /var/www/html/my/directory
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

Comment: using code deploy where you are deploying your app ?

Comment: first time setup(install) manually php and mysql then write only yaml file you need no need to add...php and mysql install lines

Comment: I am deploying my app on EC2 instances

Comment: simple you can use jenkin also..CICD rather thn using this ...i have experience of jenkin

Answer (score 0):

for first time install php and mysql you can write shell script

for second time write another shell script

each time it call different shell script file....

you can refer this one...

where there is yaml file and script folder contain sh files

```
https://github.com/enzyme-ops/laravel-code-deploy-template
```

Comment: What do you mean by "each time it call different shell script file...."? For the first time I should install the php and mysql using the sh file and add it in beforeInstall in YML file? and then for second time, remove the php and mysql installations from that same file?

Comment: yea something that type